# Is there any way to split a big file into multi parts and can combine them again?

Tags: ssh, filezilla, esxi

Is there any way to split a big file into multi parts and can combine them again?

In my case:
I want to upload a iso file (2GB) to ESXi datastore:

[image]

but there I get a issue, when I upload 4~5% the connection will break every time, maybe it's because of the firewall.

so I have a idea of spliting the iso into multi parts for uploading, after upload all of the parts, then combine them into one.

is there any tools for achieving my goal.

---

before asking the question I have tried filezilla to SSH connect (failed), but I opened ssh service of ESXi, and I can use Xshell to connect. I don't know why FileZilla cannot do it.

Comment: Well technically in Linux you can split a file my size using this command "split -b 40k myfile segment". This would create pieces of 40k each. Please run "man split" for more info. When it comes to combine them again just use the "cat" command like "cat segment 1 segment2 .... segmentN > file.iso"

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem. You’re asking how to implement your chosen solution rather than asking how to fix the problem. What browser are you using? That’s the most likely culprit.

Comment: You could upload using a utility that supports resume. But tell us more about the local and remote computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an "zip-archive" for such a task. The ESXi does know how to `unzip` on the Shell. As it seems you use Windows: The 7Zip-Gui or similiar programs also support splitting the Archive like Manuel suggested.

Nonetheless, the real problem seems odd.
And FileZilla can usually connect via SFTP, but this depends on your SSHD-Configuration on the ESXi and maybe your SSH-Key if one is used? Maybe someone tinkered with the default SSHD-Config?
Check if the following Line is present in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

`Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/vmware/openssh/bin/sftp-server -f LOCAL5 -l INFO`

I would suggest you try this as a quick fix (It seems this *Xshell* also has scp)

`scp your.iso root@your.esxi.host:/vmfs/volumes/datastore1/`

For the Upload-Problems i would try as Appleoddity also mentioned another Browser or maybe an Private-Session without any Addons loaded.
As it seems the ESXi doesn't throw an error while uploading right?

And as a side-note: [Windows SSH-Client](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) includes `scp` aswell.